# How can the connections of the Schwarzchild Metric remain torsion free?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

In Schwartzchild metric $\Gamma^r_{tt}\neq 0$, meaning that the basis $e_{t}$ changes in the direction of the R axis as we move along T axis. However, $\Gamma^r_{rt}= 0$, meaning that $e_{r}$ does not grow in the direction of the R axis as we move along the T axis. Shouldn’t it create a gap between $e_{r}$ and $e_{t}$, causing the metric connections no longer to remain torsion free? How does it avoid that?

A diagram showing $e_{r}$ and $e_{t}$ changes over time would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is only about the consequences of the first case be different from zero, while the second one is zero, it is possible to use a simpler example.

In the polar coordinate system in the plane, the derivative of $\mathbf e_\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ is not zero, and it has the direction of $\mathbf e_r$. That is: $\Gamma^r_{\theta \theta} \neq 0$.

The derivative of $\mathbf e_r$ with respect to $\theta$ is also not zero, but has no $r$ component, what means: $\Gamma^r_{r \theta} = 0$.

And of course those are metric connections, torsion free.